# алгоритм парсинга текста c++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, синтаксический-анализ, парсер

всем привет. есть строка типу JSON:

```
'users'=(('id'=10;
'name'='Serge';
'roles'=('visitor';
'moderator'
));
('id'=11;
'name'='Biales'
);
true
)
```

и нужно его сделать таким:

```
'users'=
(
    (
        'id'=10;
        'name'='Serge';
        'roles'=
        (
            'visitor';
            'moderator'
        )
    );
    (
        'id'=11;
        'name'='Biales'
    );
    true
)
```

подскажите алгоритм или вообще подскажите)

Comment: То есть просто отформатировать? Тогда смотрите исходники соответствующих утилит. Их много, [AStyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/), например, как раз плюсовая.

Comment: мне нужно написать ето в коде самому написать функцию на с++.

Comment: Конкретизируйте. Если просто расставить отступы - чётко сформулируйте условия (по скобкам, как-то ещё и т.д.) Тогда может и обойдётесь одной функцией :)

Answer (score 2):

Заводите переменную для уровня отступа.
Встречаете `(` - увеличиваете ее, переходите на новую строку, делаете отступы для каждой очередной строки 4*уровень (или сколько вам там надо).
Встречаете `)` - выводите ее на новой строке со старым отступом, переменную уменьшаете на единицу.

Примерно так.

Примерный код (дочистите сами):

```
char * s = R"aa('users'=(('id'=10;
'name'='Serge';
'roles'=('visitor';
'moderator'
));
('id'=11;
'name'='Biales'
);
true
))aa";

void space(int level)
{
    const int ident = 4;
    for(int i = 0; i < level * ident; ++i)
        cout << ' ';
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int level = 0;
    for(char * c = s; *c; ++c)
    {
        switch(*c)
        {
        case '(': cout << '\n'; space(level++); cout << "(\n"; space(level); break;
        case ')': cout << '\n'; space(--level); cout << ')'; break;
        case '\n': cout << '\n'; space(level); break;
        default: cout << *c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а что означает или делает - " R"aa( "? Такого еще не встречал

Comment: @MaximBondarenko, это новая форма записи строковых литералов, которая появилась в C++11.

Comment: @MaximBondarenko См., например, о _необработанных литералах_  [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/69ze775t.aspx) или [здесь](http://scrutator.me/post/2013/12/29/various_literals.aspx).